How to I limit the scope of TypeScript-ESLint to only apply TypeScript rules to TypeScript files?
I have a monorepo and would like to limit the application of TypeScript rules only to TypeScript files. But I would also like to still lint other JavaScript files (like Jest, Rollup, and Webpack configuration files) as server-side Node files.
I would like to do something like this (pseudocode):
export default [
  {
    ignores: [
      "packages/**/deprecated/*",
      "packages/**/build/*",
      "packages/**/coverage/*",
      "packages/**/dist/*",
      "packages/**/node_modules/*",
    ],
  },
  {
    files: ["packages/*/lib/**/*.{ts,tsx}"],
    // typescript configs only
  },
  {
    files: ["packages/*/scripts/**/*.{cjs, mjs, js}"]
    // node configs only
  }
}

However, all the documentation for the TypeScript-ESLint plugin tells you to use their config() method to generate custom TypeScript configs for ESLint. The config file generated applies TypeScript rules globally. I would still need to "exempt" other files.
How do I insert the TypeScript rules only where my comment // typescript configs only is located?
Example of what I mean (taken directly from documentation)
export default tseslint.config(
  eslint.configs.recommended,
  ...tseslint.configs.recommendedTypeChecked,
  {
    languageOptions: {
      parserOptions: {
        projectService: true,
        tsconfigDirName: import.meta.dirname,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    files: ['**/*.js'],
    ...tseslint.configs.disableTypeChecked,
  },
);

The above exports a global configuration. TypeScript rules are applied to everything that isn't explicitly listed under:
  {
    files: ['**/*.js'],
    ...tseslint.configs.disableTypeChecked,
  },

Instead of a "global then carve out exceptions" approach. I want a limited approach. I only want to declare TypeScript rules for certain files. Not this global first approach.
In my original pseudocode, if I try and spread or the rules inside of a { } block, I get an error. ConfigError: Config (unnamed): Unexpected key "0" found.  Example:
export default [
  {
    ignores: [
      "packages/**/deprecated/*",
      "packages/**/build/*",
      "packages/**/coverage/*",
      "packages/**/dist/*",
      "packages/**/node_modules/*",
    ],
  },
  {
    files: ["packages/*/lib/**/*.{ts,tsx}"],
    // typescript configs only
    ...tseslint.configs.recommended, //  This causes an error
  },
  {
    files: ["packages/*/scripts/**/*.{cjs, mjs, js}"]
    // node configs only
  }
}


Something like https://typescript-eslint.io/users/configs#disable-type-checked, perhaps? Or https://typescript-eslint.io/packages/typescript-eslint#usage-with-other-plugins? They are in fact very specific that "tseslint.config(...) is an optional helper function".

@jonrsharpe Thank you for the effort but no, this applies rules globally and then I need to carve out exceptions.  I don't want a global-first approach. I just want to apply typescript rules to specific files.  I don't want to apply global rules and then carve out exceptions.

And what is stopping you from just doing that? Use { files: ["match/these/files"], ... } to control what a given config entry is applied to like any other rules. The built-in configs are just arrays of objects, so you can .map over them as needed. Apply the global rules first, then have a block (or blocks) relating to TS files specifically.

I am being prevented because, I can't spread ...tseslint.configs.recommended or ...tseslint.configs.recommendedTypeChecked manually inside a { } block.  If I do, I get an error.  I can only spread them inside a { } block when that block is declared inside of tslint.config() method.  And that generates what I am calling a "global first" config.

You're spreading an array into an object - that gives you something like {"0": { ... }, ...}, which is rarely useful. Again, the built-in TS-ESLint configs are arrays of objects (hence being spread into config) - .map them, as the vanilla ESLint docs show. (Also "I get an error" should always be accompanied with the error on SO.)
